# Average of sums in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, average

I have a table like this:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+
| BookCode | BranchNum | OnHand |
+----------+-----------+--------+
| 0180     |         1 |      2 |
| 0189     |         2 |      2 |
| 0200     |         1 |      1 |
| 0200     |         2 |      3 |
| 0378     |         3 |      2 |
| 079X     |         2 |      1 |
| 079X     |         3 |      2 |
| 079X     |         4 |      3 |
| 0808     |         2 |      1 |
| 1351     |         2 |      4 |
| 1351     |         3 |      2 |

etc etc
```

I basically wanna do a sum(OnHand) for each BranchNum and then do avg on the sum for each of all BranchNums. The other examples I read on this site seem to have more complicated conditions than this, I just need to use avg. What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this in one step:

```
select sum(onhand) / count(distinct branchnum) as avg_per_branchnum
from atablelikethis;
```

Comment: That's quite concise, thank you. Is there not a larger function for getting the average of sums?

Comment: @user3856804 . . . No.  There is a function to get the average of a column but that is about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
select avg(sum_onhand) as avg_onhand
from
(
    select branchnum, sum(onhand) as sum_onhand
    from your_table
    group by branchnum
) tmp_tbl
```